# Android app is crashed on customer device : can customer send me crash report in case of failure on Android > 4.3?

Tags: android, crash-reports

I have app for my customer. On his device is app crashing in some cases. Because i have no access to his device i would like to get information in some crash log or report. Is some possibility to report crash by e-mail after the app crash?

Many Thanks for any advice.

Comment: use [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com)

Comment: use Crashlytics and localytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some crash report and analysis service such as [Crashlytics](https://get.fabric.io/crashlytics) by Fabric. It allows you to keep a record of every exception occurred in your application.